# Applications of dynamic range trick

Tags: post-processing

Sometimes, when postprocessing images in GIMP, I:

1. Duplicate the image to layer 2.
2. Gaussian blur layer 2 with a radius enough to remove fine detail.
3. Invert layer 2.
4. Desaturate layer 2.
5. Put layer 2 above the original image on "soft light."

The effect is that the image looks somewhat HDR-ish. An auto white-balance, perhaps saturation, and you're set.

I've noticed that this technique is useful when there are a low of shadows or highlights that can be rescued. **What are the applications of my procedure?**

Comment: I am not sure that this question is a good fit for our forum. It's fishing for other people to come up with answers that they cannot already know and which cannot be researched. As such, it really isn't exactly a question, it's a work order. Is there any way you can turn this into an actual question that may have benefit for the photographic community at large over a long duration of time?

Comment: "What are the applications of my procedure?" - the correct way a person works is: first have a problem to solve, then find a way to solve that problem. You are kind of saying: here is a way to solve a problem, now tell me, what is the problem? :-) Or I misunderstood your last question...

Comment: It seems like the technique could probably be more rapidly duplicated using some combination of curves and sharpening/unsharpening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is applicable when the result looks good, particularly, when it looks better than other techniques. Note that the definition of good varies. Can be a sense of beauty or meaningful expression for example.